# How to select the first text after a class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my HTML code:

```
<figcaption class="thumbcaption">
    New York City
    <div class="picture-attribution">
        <img class="avatar" width="16" height="16" alt="Edward Cunningham" src="http://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb2/common/avatars/thumb/7/79/3392047.png/20px-3392047.png">
            Added by <a href="/wiki/User:Edward_Cunningham">Edward Cunningham</a>
    /div>
</figcaption>
```

I need to select the first text that appears
after the **thumbcaption** class. In this case, the
text would be:

> New York City

If I do `$(".thumbcation").text()`, jQuery returns

> New York CityAdded by Edward Cunningham

How can I select only the first text? 
I tried this:

```
var text = $(".thumbcation").not(".picture-attribution");
alert($(text).text());
```

but this doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the text of the first text node

```
var text = $.trim($(".thumbcaption").get(0).firstChild.nodeValue);
//var text = $.trim($(".thumbcaption")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FbA7B/1/)

or

```
$.trim($(".thumbcaption").contents().first().text())
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FbA7B/2/)